# Can we change shape or object group border color like this?

Tags: excel, vba

I have Grouped some shape in excel. but I am not finding any option to change the group border color. when I am trying to change the group border color, the color of shapes inside the group is getting changed instead.

[image]

I also tried following VBA

```
shDesignFormat.DrawingObjects.Group
Selection.line.BorderColor = VbBlue
```

Any Help?

Comment: That's not really a "border" per-say. It's just a selection tool, so you don't control the color of it.

Comment: @braX Thanks for the reply. Any alternative way so I can insert the border inside it or change color?

Comment: You might paste a rectangle over it, if that's fine for you.

Comment: @Evil Blue Monkey But if I paste rectangle over it. it won't allow editing other shapes. As other shapes will get behind it. hope you understand what I need to achieve.

Comment: You can send the rectangle back. https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-send-an-image-to-the-back-in-excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created this code to add a rectangle under your group:

```
Sub SubAddFrame(ObjGroup As Object)

    'Declarations.
    Dim ObjRectangle As Object
    Dim DblPlus As Double
    Dim StrRectangleName As String
    Dim WrsWorksheet As Worksheet

    'Checking if ObjGroup exist.
    If ObjGroup Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Group named " & ObjGroup.Name & " not found. The frame will not be added/edited.", vbCritical, "SubAddFrame - Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Setting variables.
    StrRectangleName = "ShpFrameFromSubroutine"
    DblPlus = 6
    Set WrsWorksheet = ObjGroup.Parent

    'Checking if a previous ObjRecangle has been created with this macro.
    On Error Resume Next
    If WrsWorksheet.Shapes(StrRectangleName) Is Nothing Then
        Set ObjRectangle = WrsWorksheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 72, 72)
    Else
        Set ObjRectangle = WrsWorksheet.Shapes(StrRectangleName)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Focusing ObjRectangle.
    With ObjRectangle
        'Filling it with grid.
        With .Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorBackground1
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = -0.25
            .Patterned msoPatternDottedGrid
        End With
        'Setting the line.
        With .Line
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .Weight = 2
        End With
        'Placing it over the ObjGroup.
        .Height = ObjGroup.Height + DblPlus * 2
        .Width = ObjGroup.Width + DblPlus * 2
        .Left = ObjGroup.Left - DblPlus
        .Top = ObjGroup.Top - DblPlus
        'Setting its name.
        .Name = StrRectangleName
        'Pushing it back.
        .ZOrder msoSendToBack
    End With

End Sub
```

It can be called from another subroutine. Here an example designed according to your further instructions:

```
Sub AnyOfYourSub()

    '[You can place more of your code here]

    'Deleting "FrameFromSubroutine" (if it exists already).
    On Error Resume Next
    shDesignFormat.Shapes("ShpFrameFromSubroutine").Delete
    'Ungrouping any object (if any grouped).
    shDesignFormat.DrawingObjects.Ungroup
    On Error GoTo 0
    'Selection.ShapeRange.Ungroup
    Call SubAddFrame(shDesignFormat.DrawingObjects.group)

    '[You can place more of your code here]

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the codes as an alternative to my problem. which seems good. but with this alternative, I need some control over the inserted rectangle. i.e 1) I don't want the user to delete and resize this rectangle as a border but I want the user to change the color of its border and border width 2) it will be awesome if I can use the gridline as a background for this rectangle, so the user can easily edit other shapes inside it. Thanks

Comment: 1) Hm, no delete nor resize but changeable border's colors and width... i guess you want it to be possible as one can usually do manually, right? No added macro/items? 2) What do you mean by gridline? The sheet gridline should be visible (if already visible). Do you want a grid drawn in the rectangle it?

Comment: Gridline means rectangle background like this image https://www.google.com/search?q=image+editor+gridline&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwj77eue7PToAhU-7jgGHYEHCBwQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=image+editor+gridline&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DhIlibSWDrSmgAcAB4AIABzgSIAa4OkgELMC41LjEuMC4xLjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZw&sclient=img&ei=qXOcXrv1Fb7c4-EPgY-g4AE&bih=612&biw=1396&rlz=1C1CHBD_enIN882IN882&safe=off#imgrc=InTsC5C9ouj9KM

Comment: its something like label or photo design area.

Comment: Yes, i want gridline within a rectangle, as all other shapes will be inside a single cell, so there will be no use of worksheet gridlines. my all shapes will be in cell "B3"

Comment: So once shape design is complete, I will group all shapes with your rectangle as border and paste in other sheets.

Comment: Ok, about the unchangeable size but changeable borders: it's not possible to easily do it as far as i know. We should build specific subroutines to make the changes (protection might be turned off/on with subroutines or we might allow it when opening the workbook). For the gridline, i'm pretty sure there will be some default pattern we can use. I'll check it out.

Comment: Can we assign macro to a rectangle, so it disallows delete and reset the border size and disallow any other formatting to border?

Comment: I've edited the code for the grid. Check if it satisfies you. About the protection: i think that the easiest way is to add one or more button connected to a subroutine to change the size/color of the rectangle.

Comment: That is really looking awesome and thanks for the update. As per your last comment you said regarding subroutine I have no idea about it. but i got another idea. what if we assign a macro to rectangle. and on rectangle select, it automatically gets deselected. and with another command button, we can allow editing its border color.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212019/discussion-between-evil-blue-monkey-and-heavyload-collection).