# Selecting a chart and shape inside chart application.caller

Tags: excel, vba

I can select a shape normally with following VBA

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Select
```

I want to select a chart and shape the inside the chart. I am not finding line of code.

I tried the following but no success.

```
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Application.Caller).Select
```

**Additional information:**

Actually my chart is locked and I want to keep it locked and my sheet it protected(edit object is unchecked). I inserted shape inside the chart. My target is to edit shape inside the chart in locked mode with application.caller. So I can select the shape then I ll be able to edit it

I 'll have more than 10 shapes in chart and shapes are added dynamically with add shape button with random names. so i can target shape with its name. that is why I want to user application.caller to auto select it

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub ChartClick()

    Dim cht As Chart, clr

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Chart

    cht.Shapes("myShape").Select

'    With cht.Shapes("myShape")
'        clr = .Fill.ForeColor.RGB
'        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = IIf(clr = vbRed, vbBlue, vbRed)
'    End With

End Sub
```

...assuming your macro is linked to the chartobject and not directly to the shape contained in the chart.

You can (and should) work directly with `cht` and not use `ActiveChart`.  There's almost never any need to select/activate anything in excel in order to work with it.

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Actually my chart is locked and I want to keep it locked and my sheet it protected(edit object is unchecked). I inserted shape inside the chart. My target is to edit shape inside the chart in locked mode with application.caller. So I can select the shape then I ll be able to edit it.

Comment: I know we need to avoid select normally but here I am manually editing shape so select is necessary

Comment: Thanks for the update. but I 'll have more than  10 shapes in chart and shapes are added dynamically with add shape button with random names. so i can target shape with its name     cht.Shapes("myShape").Select    that is why I want to user application.caller to auto select it. hope you get my words.

Comment: Also, I am planning to link macro to every shape added inside the chart with add shape button.

Comment: The difficulty with this is there's no way to use `ActiveSheet.Shapes(callerName)` if the clicked shape is located in a chartobject. You will need to check each chart on the sheet and its contained shapes for a name match.  Even with a locked sheet though, you can still just click on the shape to edit it - no need for a macro?

Comment: i feel very bad that there are a lot of limitations with VBA. and feel like giving up the project .

Comment: You should not consider unfamiliarity with how it works as "limitations" - we all had to learn the same way how to do things.

Comment: i know in locked sheet we can edit shape unless we have shape property is set to locked and edit objects are unchecked with protection.

Comment: Actually my reason for inserting shapes in the chart is linked to this thread I started today  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305081/can-we-change-shape-or-object-group-border-color-like-this but with this thread also there is no direct solution as of limitation with vba.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212037/discussion-between-heavyload-collection-and-tim-williams).